# Run batch script on files modifed within last N hours

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using forfiles command to run my script on the files which were modified the same day

```
forfiles /S /D +%data% /m ????_???_*tsf /C "cmd /c c:/gInfo/gravcopy.bat @path"
```

However, I have to change it to run script only on the files modified within the last N hours (e.g. 1 hour). As I know it is not possible using forfiles.

Can anybody help me with this? I am completely not familiar with scripting in Windows and would really appreciate it.

---

EDIT:

I thought about solving this problem like that:

```
cd "c:/gInfo"

@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-3).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')"') do set newdate=%%a

for /r %%i in (????_???_*tsf) do (
    if "%%~ti" GTR "%newdate%" (
       call c:/gInfo/gravcopy.bat "%FILE_TO_INSTALL%"
    )
)
```

However, date comparison does not work properly. Any ideas on that?

Comment: `forfiles`'s `/D` option only regards the last modification date but *not* the time. Since batch scripting does not support date/time arithmetics you should consider to switch to another language, like [tag:powershell], for example…

Comment: Just to avoid changes in other scripts, is that possible to create PowerShell script, which in essence would do the same thing as this line does (run another batch script)?  

%POWERSHELL PART% /C "cmd /c c:/gInfo/gravcopy.bat @path"

Answer (score 1):

```
for /?
...
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

We can use `%~tI` to expand to the time of files in the fileset.

The format of `%~tI` is `06/22/2020 16:27` (on my computer) so integer comparisons will not work like this.

```
@ECHO OFF
CD "C:\GINFO"
FOR /F "delims=" %% in ('"powershell [DateTime]::Now.AddHours(-3).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')"') do set newdate=%%a
FOR /R %%I in ("*.tsf") do (
    set VAR=%%~tI
    IF %VAR:~5,4% GEQ %newdate:~5,4% (
    IF %VAR:~0,2% GEQ %newdate:~0,2% (
    IF %VAR:~3,2% GEQ %newdate:~3,2% (
    IF %VAR:~11,2% GEQ %newdate:~11,2% ( 
    IF %VAR:~14,2% GEQ %newdate:~14,2% (
       CALL .\gravcopy.bat "%FILE_TO_INSTALL%"
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )
)
```

Explanation:

```
FOR /R %%I in ("*.tsf") do (
REM Iterates through all the files in the current directory with the file extension .tsf. Full path not necessary, cd already changed to the directory
    set VAR=%%~tI
    REM sets the time of the file to a variable so you can get substrings
    IF %VAR:~5,4% GEQ %newdate:~5,4% ( REM Checks the year of the file and see if it is greater than or equal to the year of the other variable
    IF %VAR:~0,2% GEQ %newdate:~0,2% ( REM REM Checks the month of the file and see if it is greater than or equal to the year of the other variable (Date format varies between computers, be warned)
    IF %VAR:~3,2% GEQ %newdate:~3,2% ( REM Checks the day of the file to see if it is greater than or equal to the current day
    IF %VAR:~11,2% GEQ %newdate:~11,2% ( REM Checks hours  of the file to see if it is greater than or equal to the minute of the variable
    IF %VAR:~14,2% GEQ %newdate:~14,2% ( REM Checks minutes of the file to see if it is greater than or equal to the minute of the variable
       CALL .\gravcopy.bat "%FILE_TO_INSTALL%"
    )))))
)
```